# How does TeXit convert LaTeX to images?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, latex

I am developing a [Discord Bot](https://top.gg/bot/847826926483013649). I have used another Discord Bot called [TeXit](https://top.gg/bot/510789298321096704). How does this bot manage to convert LaTeX code to images? I have tried using [CodeCogs](https://latex.codecogs.com/), but the quality of images generated is very bad. How can I generate high quality images like TeXit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is they are all running TexLive (over 1 GB of code) and other graphics utilities like GhostScript, on quality high speed servers in real-time. Code Cogs should be fine enough, just use the appropriate settings.

```
<img src="https://latex.codecogs.com/png.image?\dpi{288}&space;$rendering&space;latex:&space;,&space;&space;&space;&space;$\overline{Mr.&space;Brawler}=&space;&space;x^{2}&space;&plus;&space;5" title="$rendering latex: , $\overline{Mr. Brawler}= x^{2} + 5" />
```

is pasted and runs here as an instant SaaS (Software as a Service)

[image]

Test it by hovering over the above instantly refreshed inline PNG image. Here is the **vector** SVG but inline on this page it is realtime converted hereto as a lower screen resolution !

[image]

**ZOOM IN with your browser to see how it changes and improves realtime !**

[image]

***For comparison*** Here is the offline output as a PDF with selectable plain text (which naturally looses the maths relationships.)

[image]

Comment: The kerning of the text in math mode hurts the eyes :)